# How to upload localhost phpmyadmin mysql procedures to server?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, routines

I am getting an error while uploading my database to server. my database has many stored procedures(routines) I am getting the following error how i resolve that ?

SQL query:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getAttractions` ()  BEGIN

SELECT * FROM attractions ;

END$$
```

MySQL said:

> 1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: it is clearly saying you , that you don't have a permission to do that , or you are on shared hosting or you are on localhost or anykind of server which doesn't allow you to process this oprations.

Comment: Then how i add a permission ?

Comment: depends on what kind of host you are using, if it's shared hosting , then you can't use these queries inside console , you have to use their cpanel to make new users and set permissions. else if you are on localhost or vps or any personal server , then you must give permissions to the users you are trying to oprate with.

Comment: i am at shared hosting and i am trying to upload my database with procedures and i am getting the above mentioned error . I already set all the permissions after creating the user in cpanel mysql option

Comment: seems like you are not allowed to do that on your shared hosting. they didn't gave you permission to do that.